# PayPal button not showing and cannot retrieve order error in PayPal

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

I am having a big issue and I tried everything best to solve this issue but unfortunelyy I cannot.

I need you guys to help me to solve this issue

I have enable the woo commerce in my client website, but I am facing problem in checkout page since the payment option are not working as per the need.
I have created a custom theme and enabled woo commerce in there.

I am using a woo commerce PayPal plugin but, the PayPal button are not displaying in my site and also logo are not there. Did I messed up something or where do I did wrong ?

page I need help is https://www.ghdcollection.com/

Normally a PayPal button will be like this

[image]

but i am getting this

[image]

Also I am getting this error in my console,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone needs answer, please see this thread below.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-paypal-payment-could-not-retrieve-order/